# jquery checkbox inside table tag not able to access

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i m trying to access all checkbox inside table tag....
initially all checkbox were inside div tag at that time below code was working fine and i was able to access the each checkbox

```
   $('#div_id').children('input').each(function()
{
    if(this.type == 'checkbox')
    {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 1)
        {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

now when i places checkbox inside table it stop working. i tried to change 'div_id' to 'table_id' still no success. any suggestions ?

**All checkboxes and table is dynamically created.**

Comment: put all your code inside document.ready ...did you ?

Comment: You can simply use `$('#div_id :checkbox[id=1]').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: what if id changes and not static like in code @Satpal

Comment: Then use `$('#div_id :checkbox[id=' + yourId + ']').prop('checked', true)`. A single line of code is good enough then `.each(`

Comment: why are you testing for an attribute of id equal 1? since ids should be unique, this makes no sense to me..

Comment: @jhohlfeld i know, it was just for understanding actual code works on different ids for matching data retrieved from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.children` only travels a single element down the tree (described here https://api.jquery.com/children/).

What you need now is `.find`, which traverses through all down the child element tree, and thus your code becomes:

```
$('div_id').find('input').each(function()
{
    if(this.type == 'checkbox')
    {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 1)
        {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The guy said his code worked fine before, so I'm guessing the div_id is just a placeholder, hashtag or no.

Comment: No probs, .find has saved me a few times!

Answer (score 2):

----------------------------- HTML Code below --------------------------

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>   

<input type="button" onclick="callFunction()" value="Click" />
```

-------------------------- JS Code below --------------------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callFunction() {

        $('table input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            alert("hi table") //This will be call 4 times.
            if (this.checked) {
                alert("hi inner") ////This will be call 2 times, only for checked checkboxes.
                //this.checked = true;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, You will see in the code that it will show alert("hi table") for all the table's items that are total 4, But you will also see that it alert("hi inner") only 2 times because it shows alert only for those check-boxes which are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector api:

$('table#id input[type=checkbox]');

will return an array with all checkbox elements.